# Creating different completion paths using form wizard - Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-formwizard

I was following the tutorial online, but I am stuck when trying to conditionally show steps in my form wizard.

views.py

```
def silver_ad_selected(wizard):
        cleaned_data = wizard.get_cleaned_data_for_step('0') or {}
        return cleaned_data.get('ad_type') == '2'

def platinum_ad_selected(wizard):
        cleaned_data = wizard.get_cleaned_data_for_step('0') or {}
        return cleaned_data.get('ad_type') == '3'

class AddWizard(SessionWizardView):
        def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
                return render_to_response('business/done.html', {
                        'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],
                })
```

urls.py:

```
add_forms = [AddForm1, AddForm2, AddForm3]

urlpatterns = patterns('listings.views',
    url(r'^addWizard/$', AddWizard.as_view(add_forms,
        condition_dict = {
                '2': silver_ad_selected or premium_ad_selected
        })),
.......
```

forms.py

```
class AddForm1(forms.Form):
        TYPE_CHOICES = (
                ('1','Basic'),
                ('2','Silver'),
                ('3','Platinum')
        )
        ad_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect)

class AddForm2(forms.Form):
        category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Category.objects.all())
        city = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = City.objects.all())
        name = forms.CharField(max_length = 200)
        address = forms.CharField(max_length = 200)
        slogan = forms.CharField(max_length=140)
        phone = forms.CharField(max_length=10)
        website = forms.URLField()
        email = forms.EmailField()

class AddForm3(AddForm2):
        twitter = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
        facebook = forms.URLField()
        description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

Basically, I only want to show the last step if the user chooses either the "Silver" option or the "Platinum" option, which is selected in step 1. Right now, no matter what I choose, only the first two steps/forms are shown.

I think that my `silver_ad_selected` and `platinum_ad_selected` methods might be the problem, but I am not sure.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your urls.py:

```
add_forms = [AddForm1, AddForm2, AddForm3]

urlpatterns = patterns('listings.views',
    url(r'^addWizard/$', AddWizard.as_view(add_forms,
        condition_dict = {
            '2': lambda wizard: wizard.silver_ad_selected() or wizard.premium_ad_selected()
        })),
```

Comment: Yes. The problem was that I was passing in a boolean condition instead of a callable function, which is exactly what your lambda is. Thanks a lot